# Python Kivy MDList- Does not return the id text of a list item when clicked on it

Tags: python, kivy

In the list created by a "FOR" below, I need to access the ID of a list item when clicked.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

from data_base import *

Window.size = (400, 700)

KV = '''
WindowManager:

    FirstWindow:
        id: screen1

    SecondWindow:
        id: screen2

    ThirdWindow:
        id: screen3


<FirstWindow>:
    name: "first"

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "alpha-j"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
        icon_size: '300sp'

    MDTextField:
        id: username_id
        size_hint_x: .9
        hint_text: "username"
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .4}


    MDTextField:
        id: senha
        size_hint_x: .9
        hint_text: "Senha"
        mode: "rectangle"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}


    MDRaisedButton:
        size_hint_x: .9
        text: "Entrar"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .2}
        on_press: root.login(root.ids.username_id.text)
        on_release: app.root.current = "second"

    MDLabel:
        text: "By Thiago Barbosa Developer"
        halign: "center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .1}



<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1, 1)

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "MDTopAppBar"


        MDBottomNavigation:

            #panel_color: "#eeeaea"
            selected_color_background: "orange"
            text_color_active: "lightgrey"

            #GLOBAL SCREEN

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                md_bg_color: (0, 255, 0)
                name: 'global'
                text: 'Global'
                icon: 'earth'

                MDBoxLayout:
                    padding: 25
                    orientation: "vertical"

                    MDScrollView:
                        size_hint: (1, .9)
                        MDList:
                            id: search_list
                            OneLineListItem:
                                id: line_1
                                text: "TEST"
                                on_release: print(root.ids.line_1.text)

                    MDBoxLayout: 
                        orientation: "horizontal"
                        size_hint: (1, .1)



            #MYSPAY SCREEN

            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'MY SPACE'
                text: 'My Space'
                icon: 'account'

                MDLabel:
                    id: user_name_myspace
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .93}
                    halign: 'center'


            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                name: 'profile edit'
                text: 'Edit'
                icon: 'book-edit'

<ThirdWindow>:
    name: "third"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (1, 1)

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "MDTopAppBar"

        MDLabel:
            id: user_name_ext
            text: "Usuário"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .93}
            halign: 'center'

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "account"
            icon_size: "180sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}

        MDLabel:
            id: user_job_myspace_ext
            text: "Profissão"
            font_size: 22
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .45}
            halign: 'center'
            bold: True


        MDLabel:
            id: competencia_myspace_ext
            text: "Especializações e Competências"
            font_size: 15
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .35}
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint: (.9, None)

'''

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstWindow(Screen):

    def login(self, username):
        print("Realizando Login"
              )
        acess = True

        print("Logado")

class SecondWindow(Screen):

    def on_enter(self):

        self.ids.search_list.add_widget(
            OneLineListItem(id="line_2", text="TEST2", on_release=lambda y: print(self.ids.line_2.text))

        )

        for x in range(50):
            self.ids.search_list.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(text=f"This is element number {x}")

            )

        for ids in self.ids:
            print(ids)


        username = MDApp.get_running_app().root.ids.screen1.ids.username_id.text

        username = "tmb.dev"
        print(username)


class ThirdWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        # self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        # self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.root


MyApp().run()
```

when the list is created by the KV language as an example in the code, on_release works correctly, when it is done by function through the code it presents an error: " AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**' "

This is the ultimate goal, to create a dynamic list that when clicked will return its text value.

```
        for x in range(50):
            item = f"item_{x}"
            self.ids.search_list.add_widget(
                OneLineListItem(id=item,
                                text=f"This is element number {x}",
                                on_release=lambda y: print(self.ids.item.text))

            )
```

Comment: The `ids` dictionary is created by the kivy language. Adding an `id` attribute in python will not result in that `id` appearing in the `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    for x in range(50):
        item = f"item_{x}"
        text = f"This is element number {x}"
        self.ids.search_list.add_widget(
            OneLineListItem(text=text, on_release=lambda y, t=text: print(t)))
```

Since you know the `text` when you create the `OneLineListItem`, just use that text in the `on_release`.